# HTML5 audio link masking?

Tags: audio, html, media

I'm trying to create a mobile ready audio player. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to "mask" the src so that a user couldn't view source and download the mp3. I'm definitely a n00b, so any simple direction would be extremely helpful (IE - use 'x' to do 'y'). I don't necessarily need code examples. Thanks!

Current:

```
<audio src="unreleased_track01mp3">
...
</audio>
```

What I'd like:

```
<audio src="01238134781239871">
...
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

You could attempt to stream the audio, but if you want to play a specific file, the user will always be able to download it if the user is able to listen to it.

Comment: obfuscation is just obfuscation, if user wants it bad enough they can find it

Comment: obfuscation would probably be good enough. Could this be accomplished in JS?

Comment: Obfuscation would probably be best done either by renaming the files into random names or by using server-side url rewriting (mod_rewrite, PHP, whatever). You could also dynamically create the audio tag with JS which might make it a bit trickier to directly find the code.